# How can the cursor position in VIM be synchronized on multiple machines?

Tags: vim, sync, cursor

I know that vim can remember the cursor's position of a previous editing session. But this feature is not so helpful while I'm working on a C source file both at home and office using two machines. The file I'm editing is synchronized via iCloud Drive. So I suppose only the C file itself is being synchronized, but the 'hidden file' storing the cursor position for VIM is not.

Is there a way to synchronize the cursor's position in my case?

Comment: Short of copying your .viminfo file to a USB stick you carry with you or upload and download from your clound drive? That sounds tricky. Could you configure your .vimrc to store your .viminfo on your cloud drive? I've never used them, so I don't know how they work in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just found "session-file" for vim which perfectly solves my problem. By typing a ":mksession" command in normal mode,  a new file named "Session.vim" will be saved. It captures all the settings for the current session - even those for multiple files. When I work from the other computer, just typing "vim -S Session.vim" will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Just to convert that guess of a comment into an official answer since it turned out to be right...

Configure your .vimrc to store your .viminfo on your cloud drive.

Or, as you noted, at the end of your session, run `:mksession filename`, specifying a path that would put it on your cloud drive.  Then at the start of your next session, :source that file into vim.